# Amazon Affiliate banner and other product are not showing up on my site in Firefox and edge browser

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

[https://infoaroundtheworld.com](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) in which i have added Amazon Affiliate banner, that is not showing in Firefox, opera and and edge browser for me and my users as well. But in Chrome it is showing.

Please can any one guide my how can fix it.

Thanks

I thought it is because of http protocol script.
so i tried with https protocol as well still not working.

below is the code for my banner.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
      var aax_size='300x250';
      var aax_pubname = 'infoaroundthe-21';
      var aax_src='302';
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://c.amazon-adsystem.com/aax2/assoc.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox in "Enhanced Tracking Protection" mode will block tracking content by default:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/enhanced-tracking-protection-firefox-desktop#w_what-enhanced-tracking-protection-blocks